# verb + object + to infinitive?

Tags: grammar, direct-objects, indirect-objects

> I want *you* to go.
>
> I want *him* to go.

> She told *me* to give you the key. ( to whom ? ) me !

you and him in these sentences are used as object pronouns. so it is considered as an object.

> I want *my father* to go to Germany.

So what questions will we ask when finding the object in this sentence? (my father ) Is the object in this sentence a direct or indirect object? Can you explain with examples?

Comment: @Sam "to go to Germany" is not a preposition phrase but a subordinate (infinitival) clause.

Comment: Okkkk, it's by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

[1] *I want you* [*to go*].

[2] *I want him* [*to go*].

[3] *She told me* [*to give you the key*].

[4] *I want my father* [*to go to Germany*].

The analysis is like this:

In each case the bracketed element is a subordinate (infinitival) clause functioning as complement of the matrix clause verbs "want / told".

The intervening noun phrases "you"/"him"/"me"/"my father" are the syntactic objects of the verbs "want/told", and the understood (semantic) subjects of the subordinate clauses.

There is no indirect object in any of the examples.